# songs: formatting songs with two voices

Tags: formatting, songs

I'm currently rewriting the songbook of our scout group with LaTeX and the songs package. But I have problems with a couple of songs which are sing in two voices with overlapping parts.

For example this is one of the songs I have problems with:

[image]

Every second line in the verses is the second voice.

As this page was created in MS Word we had no problems with placing the words
under the right chords. Does anybody know how to do this with the songs package?

This is an example of what I achieved so far including an example song and the one I have problems with:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bookmarks,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[chorded,noshading]{songs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\songcolumns{1}

\begin{document} 

\renewcommand{\thesongnum}{P.\arabic{songnum}}
\begin{songs}{}

\beginsong{Schließ Aug' und Ohr}
\beginverse
Schließ \[a]Aug' und Ohr für \[E]eine Weil vor \[d]dem Getös' \[E]der \[a]Zeit.
\lrep Du \[C]heilst es nicht und \[G]hast kein \[E]Heil als \[a]wo dein \[E7]Herz sich \[a]weiht. \rrep

\ifchorded
{\nolyrics Zwischenspiel: \[a] \[E] \[E7] \[a]} 
\fi
\endverse


\beginverse
Dein ^Amt ist hüten, ^harren, sehn im ^Tag die E^wig^keit.
\lrep Du ^bist schon so im ^Weltge^schehen be^fangen ^und be^freit. \rrep

\ifchorded
{\nolyrics Zwischenspiel: \[a] \[E] \[E7] \[a]} 
\fi
\endverse

\beginverse
Die ^Stunde kommt, da ^man dich braucht – dann ^sei du ganz ^be^reit.
\lrep Und ^in das Feuer, ^das ver^raucht, wirf ^dich als ^letztes ^Scheit. \rrep
\endverse
\endsong

\beginsong{Wenn der Abend naht}
\textnote{Zweistimmig zu singen.}
\beginverse
Wenn der Abend naht ganz sacht und leis’,
                                                     (Wenn der Abend naht ganz sacht und
finden wir uns ein im Feuerkreis.
leis’,)                               (finden wir uns ein.)
\endverse

\beginchorus
Und wer nie an seine Freunde denkt und auch nie den roten Tschai ausschenkt,
der kann bleiben wo er ist.
Draußen weht gewiss ein kalter Wind, doch die Feuer nicht erloschen sind
für uns Sänger, wie ihr wisst.
\endchorus

\beginverse
Schatten flackern am Ruinenrand.
                                        (Schatten flackern am Ruinen-
Hat das Singen dich nicht längst gebannt?
rand.)                                         (dich nicht längst gebannt?)

Wer da glaubt, er könnt’ alleine geh’n,
                                             (Wer da glaubt, er könnt’ alleine
wird in dieser Welt sehr leicht verweh’n.
gehn,)                                      (wird sehr leicht verweh’n.)
\endverse

\beginchorus
Und wer nie an seine Freunde denkt und auch nie den roten Tschai ausschenkt,
der kann bleiben wo er ist.
Draußen weht gewiss ein kalter Wind, doch die Feuer nicht erloschen sind
für uns Sänger, wie ihr wisst,
für uns Sänger, wie ihr wisst.
\endchorus
\endsong

\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Regarding the question what I tried before posting:
I was just searching the web for a solution on how to indent this text blocks to the right position but wasn't able to find anything. I would also be happy if anybody has an idea how to display the song in an other way.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We do not like external links here, please provide a screenshot of your song. And most important: Show us, what you have tried in code and ask specific questions on your problems. We do not want to do all work for you, but we really like to help. Show some effort and reduce the working time to us. Thanks.

Comment: could you edit your post and give us one song you did successfully? Like this we will do the same style as in you other songs. As an extra, you could explain what you have tried for the second voice line.

Comment: I edited my post:
@LaRiFaRi: I didn't want anybody to do my work. I just need help on how to do it as I have no clue where to start. I'm sorry if anybody got this wrong it wasn't my intention :(

Comment: Perfect. I know, you don't. That are just standard questions as most new users here tend to give too less information. I never used `songs` so it would cost me much time to reproduce your status quo. You could now reduce your code to the absolute minimum as long as it shows how you are setting the songs. I tried to use the package `leadsheets` for your case but did not succeed. I hope others will have some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

After a few more hours of searching an reading the documentation again and again I found out that you can insert spaces by adding `~` instead of regular spaces (was a bit hidden). It does not look very nice in the source code but I does the job.

I also used two self defined macros to eliminate the space above the un-chorded lines. Everything it does is to turn off the chords before the un-chorded line start and re-enables them after the line ends.

```
\ifchorded
  \newcommand{\stopchords}{\chordsoff}
  \newcommand{\resumechords}{\chordson}
\else
  \newcommand{\stopchords}{}
  \newcommand{\resumechords}{}
\fi
```

Hopefully no one has the idea to adjust the font(size) of the text...

[image]

```
\beginsong{Wenn der Abend naht}
\textnote{Zweistimmig zu singen.}
\beginverse
\[C]Wenn der \[G]Abend \[F]naht ganz \[a]sacht und \[G]leis',~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\[d]~~~~~~~~~~\[G]
\stopchords
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(Wenn der Abend naht ganz sacht und
\resumechords
\[C]finden \[G]wir uns \[F]ein im \[a]Feuerk\[G]reis.~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\[d]~~~~~\[G]
\stopchords
leis',)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(finden wir uns ein.)
\resumechords
\endverse

\beginchorus
Und wer \[C]nie an seine \[G]Freunde denkt und auch \[a]nie den roten \[E7]Tschai ausschenkt,
der kann \[C]bleiben \[G7]wo er \[C]ist.
Draußen \[C]weht gewiss ein \[G]kalter Wind, doch die \[a]Feuer nicht er\[E7]loschen sind
für uns \[C]Sänger, \[G7]wie ihr \[C]wisst.
\endchorus

\beginverse
\[^]Schatten \[^]flackern \[^]am Ru\[^]inen\[^]rand.~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\[^]~~~~~\[^]
\stopchords
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(Schatten flackern am Ruinen-
\resumechords
\[^]Hat das \[^]Singen \[^]dich nicht l\[^]ängst ge\[^]bannt?~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\[^]~~~~~~~\[^]
\stopchords
rand.)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(dich nicht längst gebannt?)
\resumechords
\endverse

\beginverse
\[^]Wer da \[^]glaubt, er \[^]könnt' all\[^]eine \[^]geh'n,)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\[^]~~~~~~~~\[^]
\stopchords
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(Wer da glaubt, er könnt' alleine
\resumechords
\[^]wird in \[^]dieser \[^]Welt sehr l\[^]eicht ver\[^]weh'n.~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\[^]~~~~\[^]
\stopchords
gehn,)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(wird sehr leicht verweh'n.)
\resumechords
\endverse

\beginchorus
Und wer \[C]nie an seine \[G]Freunde denkt und auch \[a]nie den roten \[E7]Tschai ausschenkt,
der kann \[C]bleiben \[G7]wo er \[C]ist.
Draußen \[C]weht gewiss ein \[G]kalter Wind, doch die \[a]Feuer nicht er\[E7]loschen sind
für uns \[C]Sänger, \[G7]wie ihr \[C]wisst,
für uns \[C]Sänger, \[G7]wie ihr \[C]wisst.
\endchorus
\endsong
```